# Titanium: integration of admob module manifest error

Tags: android, admob, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

while trying to integrate admob in my current app, after unzipping the module in my folder, I edited my tiapp.xml and added:

```
<modules>
    <module version="2.0" platform="android">ti.admob</module>
</modules>
```

after trying to run the app i got the following error:

`Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize'). [ERROR] Error generating R.java from manifest`

any thoughts about how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, I found the answer.

Titanium wrote in their Github that this is version 2.0 when actually it's 1.1
changing the XML to

WTH Titanium?!?!?!?!

Comment: Hey I 'm using this Module but I have some problem with this. When i run in device or simulator the Some error occur 
[357,8]ti:/module.js
Uncaught Error: Request module not found : ti.admob
throw new Error("Request module not found :"+request);

Answer (score 1):

try this 
change in tiapp.xml

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
            <tool-api-level>14</tool-api-level>
 </android>
<modules>
        <module platform="android" version="2.0.1">ti.admob</module>
    </modules>
```